Opera GX Mod Issue: Unexpected data after root element
I'm trying to make an Opera GX mod and I'm getting the error "Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 37, column: 6, Unexpected data after root element."  I have tried everything I can think of. This is my code, any tips or solutions?
{   "name": "Shikanoko Nokonoko Koshitantan",
    "description": "shikanoko nokonoko koshitantan shikanoko nokonoko koshitantan shikanoko nokonoko koshitantan shikanoko nokonoko koshitantan shikanoko nokonoko koshitantan",
    "developer":
    {
        "name": "Chaosuu"
    },
    "icons":
    {
        "512": "file.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "mod":
    {
       "license": "license.txt",
      "payload": {
         "background_music": [ "music/shikanokonokonokokoshitantan.mp3" ]
      },
            "wallpaper":
            {
                "dark":
                {   
                    "image": "wallpaper/dark.png",
                    "text_color": "#FFFFFF",
                    "text_shadow": "#757575"
                },
                "light":
                {
                    "image": "wallpaper/video.webm",
                    "first_frame": "wallpaper/first_frame.jpeg",
                    "text_color": "#FFFFFF",
                    "text_shadow": "#0B000E"
                }
            }
        },
        "schema_version": 1
    },
        "version": "1.0"
},

I have tried messing with the braces and using code from manifests from other mods

Please provide the complete JSON code. The provided snippet seems to have mismatched braces.

The issue you're encountering with your JSON manifest for the Opera GX mod is due to some syntax errors and structural inconsistencies. You can validate your JSON online using JSON validator.
I have removed extra commas after "license.txt" and after the closing brace of "mod" and removed extra closing braces and commas after "version": "1.0".
{
    "name": "Shikanoko Nokonoko Koshitantan",
    "description": "shikanoko nokonoko koshitantan shikanoko nokonoko koshitantan shikanoko nokonoko koshitantan shikanoko nokonoko koshitantan shikanoko nokonoko koshitantan",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Chaosuu"
    },
    "icons": {
        "512": "file.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "mod": {
        "license": "license.txt",
        "payload": {
            "background_music": [
                "music/shikanokonokonokokoshitantan.mp3"
            ]
        },
        "wallpaper": {
            "dark": {
                "image": "wallpaper/dark.png",
                "text_color": "#FFFFFF",
                "text_shadow": "#757575"
            },
            "light": {
                "image": "wallpaper/video.webm",
                "first_frame": "wallpaper/first_frame.jpeg",
                "text_color": "#FFFFFF",
                "text_shadow": "#0B000E"
            }
        }
    },
    "schema_version": 1,
    "version": "1.0"
}



You can improve this answer by highlighting the changes made to bring it into compliance rather than just posting the "corrected" JSON with no further details.

Until this answer is updated, Raveena has removed the comma at the end of the file and also removed the one extra curly-brace (}) located close to the end of the JSON object (the one removed here was between "schema_version" and "version", but you might need to remove the one from before the "schema_version" line instead).

Trying this solution just gave me the error "Required int value 'schema_version' is missing from 'mod'."
